# Telegram account

Tags: telegram

I recently lost my Android phone. What I want to know is if I permanently delete my telegram account are there still videos and photos viewable on my phone. I never used the save to gallery option but I heard somewhere that the media files are still there.
Thanks.

Comment: you can erase your device from https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager (btw use threema or signal only)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting your Telegram account will not uninstall the Telegram application on your lost phone. So, depending on how you protected the access to your phone, your media files received or sent using Telegram can still be accessible.

As a side note (because the original question was asked on security.stackexchange.com), be advised that the security of Telegram is dubious at best. If this issue is important for you, you could use this incident as an opportunity to switch to a more secure messaging app.

Comment: why is telegram security dubious?

Comment: @yeah_well Because its custom protocol is full of quirks that have no real purpose (and included at first a backdoor). Even though it has been improved, we cannot trust that the developers know what they are doing. The encryption is deactivated by default (for no reason) and not possible for group chats. People are thus mislead in thinking that their conversation's confidentiality is ensured. It has not been subjected to public audits (unlike Signal or Wire). Its security depends on its servers and the goodwill of their owner.